# Project Euler #22, off by 158,055

Tags: r, splitstackshape

I'm currently working through [Project Euler problem 22](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22) which has the following challenge:

*Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.*

*For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.*

*What is the total of all the name scores in the file?*

The file can be downloaded using the above link. I've written the below code to solve the problem:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(splitstackshape)

#read in data from http://projecteuler.net/problem=22
names=sort(t(read.table("names.txt",sep=",")))

#letters to numbers conversion vectors
from=LETTERS[seq(1,26)]
to=as.character(seq(1,26))

#function to replace all letters with corresponding numbers
gsub2 = function(pattern, replacement, x, ...){
  for(i in 1:length(pattern))
    x = gsub(pattern[i],paste(replacement[i]," ",sep=""), x, ...)
  x
}

#create df, run function, create row number var for later calculation
df=data.frame(names=names)
df$name.num = gsub2(from,to,df$names)
df$rownum=seq(1,nrow(df))

#split letter values, add across rows, multiply by row number to get name score and sum 
df=concat.split(df,"name.num"," ")
df$name.sum=rowSums(df[,4:15],na.rm=TRUE)
df$name.score=df$name.sum*df$rownum
print(sum(df$name.score,na.rm=TRUE))
```

My result appears to be off 158,055 (I get `871040227` where it should be `871198282`). I've spot checked parts of it, and it appears that the list of names is sorted correctly, and that the name scores are compiling correctly (for instance, I also get `COLIN=49174`). I've also read other threads troubleshooting this problem on SO, but they're mostly in Python and the problems seem to be different than mine. My suspicion is that either the `names.txt` file is somehow not being read in right or that perhaps the method I'm using (`concat.split` from the `splitstackshape` package) to split the `df$name.num` is incorrect, though it seems to be working correctly.

Any ideas?

Also, any suggestions on how to improve/simplify my code are more than welcome!

Comment: As pointed out, there's a 'NA' in the names list, so it may cause problems.

Comment: Looks like that's a good place to start troubleshooting. Thanks! Any what kind of name is "NA" anyway... :)

Comment: In R `NA` means 'not available'...So R may think you have missing data when it finds the 'NA' string. Try this: `scan(textConnection(c('NA', 'foo')), what= '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @MrFlick, there's a 'NA' in the names list, so you need to treat it.

```
x = sort(scan('http://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt', what = '', sep =',', na.strings = ""))
s = sapply(x, function(w){
    match(w, x) * sum(match(strsplit(w, '')[[1]], LETTERS))
 })
print(sum(s))

# 871198282
```

Comment: Wow, much shorter than mine, but still not the right answer either... Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

I used to have fun doing the Euler problems in R. Here's my solution to 22.

```
namesscore<-function(name) {
    score<-0;
    for(s in 1:nchar(name)) {
        score<-score + which(substr(name,s,s)==LETTERS[1:26])
    }
    score
}
names<-scan("prob022.txt", "character", sep=",", quote="\"", na.strings="")
name.pos <- rank(names)
name.val <- sapply(names,namesscore)
sum(name.pos*name.val)
# [1] 871198282
```

There is a name "NA" in the list which may cause you problems.

Comment: Would `scan` automatically drop that?

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers correct and for catching the "NA" problem. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @rmbaughman Understood. I embarrassed that I used a for loop back then (I did this a long time ago, 5 years ago actually). I should probably try all of those again with what I know now. But really that "NA" was the trick as far as the R implementation goes. I don't think other languages would have the same problem.